# Long arguments list, how to process them nicely, now I have many if/else statements ... pure C

Tags: c

I have an application where the arguments list cant be reeeealy long. I can run my app like this:

`./app -operations a b c d e f g h i j ...`

And so on. My `a,b,c ...` are algorithms which I would like to run (functions defined in my code). To be able to execute them, I have something like this:

```
if(a)
 funA();

if(b)
 funB();

if(c)
 funC();

...
```

It does not look nice, does it? I must say, there's much more calls than just 26, since my application grows and grows, my arguments list grows too. I'm looking for a fancy way to make it simpler/prettier. Is it possible, anyone with an idea?

I dont want to use C++ nor external libraries for making it simpler. Can it be done in pure C?

Comment: Do the functions have different parameters, or are they all actually w/o parameters?

Comment: @OldProgrammer: some of them have same parameters, while others have different arguments

Comment: Why do you not want to use a library?  You could do this in straight C, but people have already done it.  I know it's not what you asked for, but consider gnu getopt.  Or you could just read its source code for ideas.

Comment: Too many `if`s mean that a lookup table is called for.

Comment: is this for micro-controller stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **very** simplified possible option:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    // create a common structure to hold all your
    // function parameters;
    typedef struct Parameters
    {
      int p1;
      int p2;
    } Param_Type;


    // sample function 1
    void func1( Param_Type *params ) {
        printf("hi from func1: %d\n", params->p1 );
    }

    // sample function 2
    void func2( Param_Type *params ) {
            printf("hi from func2: %d\n", params->p2 );
    }

    int main() {


        Parameters p;
            // parse the command line and populate the parameters struct;
        p.p1 = 1;
        p.p2 = 1;

       //create a lookup table with pointers to each function.
       void (*F_A[2])(Param_Type *) = {func1, func2}; 

       //You will still need some function, that given a set of arguments, can
       // derive and return an index into the array that maps to the correct
       / function.

        int func_idx = your_mapping_function(...) // todo

       // dispatch the correct function call.

        (*F_A[func_idx])(&p);


        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `getopt()` to read the command line parameters.
And I don't see any optimization in the way you are deciding what action to take depending upon the arguments. I'd say it's just a bad design of doing things. You could try changing your approach.

Comment: Ok, `getopt` is an option but how can it be done differently? I can't change my arguments list, for some reason I need to have all my options as application's arguments. What other approach can be used here? Cheers

Comment: To answer that, I should know what your arguments are and how do they drive the flow of code, how they depend on each other.

Comment: OKay. I see you calling a set of 3-4 different functions with different arguments. And I am guessing you run only one algorithm in a single run of your program. So, you can save function pointers in an array and then depending upon your input number, invoke that function pointer directly with the arguments that you read form command line. You won't require to run the `if()` statments in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use enums and function pointers to define handlers for every different set of arguments.
Something in the lines of:

```
typedef enum {
    ARG_A,
    ARG_B,
    ARG_C,
    // etcetera
    MAX_ARGS
} CmdArgId;

bool cmdArgStates[MAX_ARGS];

typedef void (*CmdHandler_f)();
CmdHandler_f cmdHandlers[MAX_ARGS] = {
   // TODO: set function pointers
};

int main()
{
    // set cmdArgStates[] indexes to true or false,
    // according to the program command line.
    ParserCmdArgs();

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARGS; ++i)
    {
        if (cmdArgStates[i] == true)
        {
            cmdHandlers[i]();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the handler functions to have different numbers of arguments, you can define a common function with a fixed number of args and just ignore them when they are not needed. I.e.: `typedef void (*CmdHandler_f)();` could also de something like `typedef void (*CmdHandler_f)(int, int, int);`

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to create a structure that can be used to abstract each command line option. Here is a possible method you could use to implement that idea :

- Create a structure that can represent each function you need to
  support, and have it hold a pointer to the function and a string for the search key.
- Create an array of this structure and initialize the members accordingly
- Use an algorithm, such as a binary search, to find the key in the structure array when looping through the command line arguments.
- Once you have the structure from the key, you can then call the function which will handle the behavior desired in the option.

It's possible this won't apply to your situation, but this really is an implementation specific problem. If you want a more specific solution, you should probably post more details about your functions and the implementation behind them.